# Git reset --hard at the beginning and there is no commit to return back

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, undo, git-reset

I just initialized .git folder to my project with `git init` command. It was a problem and I just wanted to make `git reset --hard` and try again. But `reset --hard` command deleted all the files that I haven't committed yet. Right now it is a empty folder with just a .git folder :(.

Can I go back to initialized time that does not have any changes yet with git. Because there is also nothing in the recycle bin.

Comment: You can use `git reflog`

Comment: @DreamBold No reflog will get OP their uncommited changes back.

Answer (score 2):

You ran `git add .` before `git reset --hard`, right? If so, the good news is that you could still find the contents of the deleted files.

```
git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects | grep blob
```

The command lists all the blob objects in the format of `<sha1value> blob <size_in_byte>`. They represent the contents of the added files. You can use `git show <sha1value>` or `git cat-file -p <sha1value>` to print the content.

The bad news is that there is no way to automatically bring back the names of directories and files. They are stored upon `git commit`, which you didn't run. If the directory structure is simple and the amount of the files is small, you could restore them by memory.

```
git show $sha1value > $filename
```